# Wysiwyg images are not displaying in Emails

Tags: magento-1.9, email, image, wysiwyg

I have added an editor field in one of the custom forms by following code.

```
//Editor configuration    
$wysiwygConfig = Mage::getSingleton('cms/wysiwyg_config')->getConfig(array(            
    'add_variables' => false,
    'add_widgets' => false,
    'add_images' => false,
    'files_browser_window_url' => Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->getUrl('adminhtml/cms_wysiwyg_images/index')
 ));

//Editor field
$fieldset->addField('text', 'editor', array(
    'label'     => Mage::helper('masters')->__('Template Content'),
    'class'     => 'required-entry',
    'required'  => true,
    'name'      => 'text',
    'config'    => $wysiwygConfig,
    'wysiwyg'   => true
));
```

It displays images correctly in admin. But when I email content of editor field, images are not displayed. I tried to inspect image URL in email window and I got

```
http://localhost/magento/index.php/admin/cms_wysiwyg/directive/___directive/ef3tftZWfRpYSfBf1cffmw9Ind3eWcvdGf,/key/512fg8a4e56b1e6/
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why is it localhost?

Comment: I have replaced my actual domain with localhost/magento

Answer (score 0):

Try to filter the WYSIWYG editor value by following code

```
Mage::helper('cms')->getBlockTemplateProcessor()->filter('your WYSIWYG editor value');
```

Then append that value to the email content.

Hope this may help to you.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but it is also not working. I have found an alternative solution though. I have modified browser.js and overriden Mage_Cms_Helper_Wysiwyg_Images helper file to get desired URL